# how much is 100 volts

Tags: electrostatics

looks like 100 volts potential can be produced by friction (I just solved a problem using voltage for a point charge). That seems like a small voltage and you possibly cant do much work with that kind of voltage.  But then you have appliances running on 110 volts which can do lot of work. So confused

Answer (score 1):

I assume the 100 V that you calculated is something like the static charge produced when rubbing objects together.   This voltage can produce a current a tiny fraction of a second ... the duration of a spark, for example.  An appliance has to draw current all day.  The appliance needs a continuous supply of charge, and that charge is provided by the utility company.   The charge on the rubbed objects cannot be replenished.